# Nancyfx Owin Self Host

Tags: owin, nancy

I am testing Nancyfx. I have successfully tested a console app:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:8080"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("START");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My nancy module is simple:

```
public class Logon : NancyModule
{
    public Logon()
    {
        Get["/"] = p =>
        {
            return "OK";
        };
    }
}
```

My owin startup:

```
public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

All working ok. However when I try to start a host from another project I cant get it to work.

If I call this from another project:

```
public class NancyHost
{
    public IDisposable Start(int port)
    {
         return WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http\\localhost:8080");
    }
}
```

I have put a breakpoint on the owin startuo1 and it's being called but when I go into a browser to test the browser says localhost refused to connect?

I presume that the IDisposable return by:

```
return WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http\\localhost:8080");
```

Is wrong

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code where I try to start the host:

```
private IDisposable host;
NancyHost nServ;

private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nServ = new NancyHost();
    host =   nServ.Start(8080);         
}
```

Comment: Notice the ReadLine? It starts the server, keeps the socket open and waits. What you're doing is starting the server and then automatically returning

Comment: Thanks yep I was aware of the readline in the console app but I was using a winfrom app to test and I thought the host would remain running until I disposed it.